# Multiple ways to check the balance of ERC20 tokens of smart contract: which to use?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, balances

I have a smart contract which holds ERC20 tokens. There's a function in it, in which I need to check whether the smart contract has enough balance, and if so, send out some tokens to a user.

I thought that this would work properly:

```
if (address(this).balance > 123) {
  //.....
```

However, I've found out that there're also the **functions** `balance(..)` and `balanceOf(...)`.

Therefore, there're  3 ways, in total, to check the balance? What's the difference between them? Which is used in what cases?

Comment: I always use balanceOf(address) for ERC20 tokens, and it never failed me. (It must have been dozen thousands of transactions by now) So I would feel confident using it.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are confusing `address(this).balance` which will give you the native token balance (ETH, MATIC, BNB...) of the contract, with `IERC20(tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this))` which gives you how many tokens of the ERC20 contract this address has.

If your goal is to check how many ERC20 token your contract has, you should implement the second option.

You can also checkout this OpenZeppelin documentation: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-balanceOf-address-